# AttributeError of threading.Thread in Python 2.7.5

Tags: python-2.7

When I run the following code, I got an AttributeError:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import time

def worker():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1) # Seconds
        print i

threading.Thread(target=worker).start()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yaa110/workspace/Python27/src/threading.py", line 3, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/home/yaa110/workspace/Python27/src/threading.py", line 11, in <module>
    threading.Thread(target=worker).start()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
```

I run Python 2.7.5 on Ubuntu 13.10.
Moreover when I use python via terminal, then I got no Error by inputing codes line by line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've created a python file, or module in the current directory of this script which is titled `threading` or `threading.py`. This causes your `import threading` to import the wrong threading library; one where there is no Module named Thread in it!

Rename it and all should be ok. Running the script on my 2.7.2 worked just fine!

Comment: @yaa110: That's not true. Your Python script is in fact named `/home/yaa110/workspace/Python27/src/threading.py`. Rename it.

Comment: Thank you. I checked again the folder and I found a file named "threading.pyc". So I deleted that file and now it works,